# Find the average of a potentially infinite number of integers in C

Tags: c

I need to write a program in C that reads integers as entered by a user, stopping when 0 is entered, and then finds the average of them.
This is what I have currently

```
int main(void) {

int total, h = -1, sum2 = 0;
float mean;

printf("\nYou've chosen Average.\nEnter the numbers you want to find the average of with a 0 at the end (eg. 2 1 5 12 0)\n");
    scanf(" %d", &total);
    while (total > 0) {
        h++;
        sum2 += total;
        scanf (" %d\n", &mean);
        mean = (float)total / h;                        
    }                   
    printf("Average = %.2f\n", mean);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Update

```
int main(void) {

int total, h = 0;
float mean;

printf("\nYou've chosen Average.\nEnter the numbers you want to find the average of with a 0 at the end (eg. 2 1 5 12 0)\n");
    while (scanf (" %d", &total) == 1 && total > 0) {
        h++;
        sum2 += total;  
    }
    mean = (float)total / h;                    
    printf("Average = %.2f\n", mean);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's simple, you just need to calculate how much a number divided by `0` is and then replace the `mean` with the answer.

Comment: Any help with what? You haven't listed the problem with the program. Does it work? What is your question?

Comment: Well it compiles and runs, but doesn't progress past the [user input](http://i.imgur.com/PUQM6Ug.png), and will eventually crash

Comment: Shouldn't your `scanf` be ***inside*** the loop? (e.g. `while (scanf ("%d", &total) == 1 && total > 0) {.. stuff ..}`) You don't really even need the `total > 0` test, you can divide `0` just not by `0` without issue.

Comment: `scanf (" %d\n", &mean);` --> `scanf (" %d\n", &total);`? And you don't need to calculate the mean inside the loop.

Comment: `scanf (" %d\n", &mean);` --> `scanf ("%d", &total);`  mean --> total, drop space, drop \n .  That \n "delays" `scanf()` return - that is causing the "doesn't progress past the user input".

Comment: "stopping when 0 is entered" --> then why `while (total > 0)` instead of `while (total != 0)`?

Comment: I've updated the post to take into account the corrections made, however the average is always 0 regardless of which numbers are used. As to why I use something instead of something else, it's because I have very little idea of what I'm doing

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.  The problem should become apparent.

Comment: Hint: in new code, where is `+=`?

Comment: In the same place as it was before, didn't notice I'd missed it from the updated code

Comment: if I change `mean = (float) total / h;` to `mean = (float)sum2 / h;` I get a value for the average. Thank you everyone for the help

Comment: Hmm, in the new code `sum2 ` is not declared, suggest posted true tested code.

Comment: Detail: no need for `mean`, just use `printf("Average = %.2f\n", 1.0*total / h);` and avoid using casts and `float`.   Also why so narrow with `total`, how about `long long total`?

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you want is a *[cumulative moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average)*; you update the average with each new input value.

In pseudocode, it would look something like

```
cma = 0; // mean is initially 0
n = 0;   // n is number of inputs read so far
while nextValue is not 0
  cma = (nextValue + (n * cma )) / (n + 1)
  n = n + 1
end while
```

Let's look at how it would work with a sequence like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0`:

```
cma = 0;
n = 0
nextValue = 1
cma = (1 + (0 * 0))/(0 + 1) == 1/1 == 1
n = 1
nextValue = 2
cma = (2 + (1 * 1))/(1 + 1) == 3/2 == 1.5 // (1 + 2)/2 == 1.5
n = 2
nextValue = 3
cma = (3 + (2 * 1.5))/(2 + 1) == 6/3 == 2 // (1 + 2 + 3)/3 == 2
n = 3
nextValue = 4
cma = (4 + (3 * 2))/(3 + 1) == 10/4 == 2.5 // (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)/4 == 2.5
n = 4
nextValue = 5
cma = (5 + (4 * 2.5))/(4 + 1) == 15/5 == 3 // (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)/5 == 3 
n = 5
nextValue = 0
```

You should be able to translate that pseudocode into C fairly easily.  Remember that integer division gives an integer result - `1/2` will yield `0`, not `0.5`.  At least one operand must be a floating point type to get a floating point result.  You will probably want to use `double` for your inputs and result.